# js file cant use jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a weird bug where I include this files in my  section

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="js/barScriptOOP.js"></script>
```

in the barScriptOOP.js I have this

```
function position_bar(){
    //global variable
    this.sizes      = Array();
}
//class methods => getData (from xml file), draw(draws the bar )
position_bar.prototype ={
    getData: function(is_load){

        var xmlData = Array();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "Bar.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            context: this,
            success: function(xml) {

                //extracting new data - some code here
                                xmldata = "blabla";
                this.draw(is_load, xmlData);
            }
        })//end ajax

    }, 
//other functions
```

when I use this script, I get a '$.ajax is not a function' error.
1. I tried editing out `this.draw(is_load, xmlData);` and it didn't errored me. 
my programs rpeatly calls the getData function.

note: I also get a `'$.browser is undefined'` error which is in the other function(this is the first error I get).

meaning ==> the going to another function unables jquery.

any idead what is going on here?

Comment: try to change `$.` by `jQuery.`

Comment: is there any possibility there's framework other than jQuery being used that uses $? sometimes that would raise conflicts.. try `jQuery.ajax` to check it out... else the script might be executed before the jQuery-latest is being included which is quite unlikely.. just assumptions though

Comment: the posted code executes fine here, so something (important) is missing to reproduce your problem

Comment: Make sure you call jQuery related thing after jquery loaded by put that (I mean call function part) in $(function(){//Put your call here});

Comment: thanks mgraph, I replaced every $ to jQuery an it worked. this is one the weirdest things.. it all worked before with the '$' sign..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using $ as your jquery reference, try putting this line at the start of your script

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(function() {
  alert('doc ready');
});
```

(also, it's strange that your script tag doesn't have a type attribute set, though I doubt that's the issue)

Comment: HTML5 (assuming the doctype is HTML5) doesn't require a type on script elements.